# Average of floating numbers Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

Really confused right now on how to get the average of two different float arrays. So far I understand how to do one array, but for the second array I haven't got a clue. Some reason I thought it was pretty simple, but the second array is a little more complicated.

Here's the cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" double Average (int, double []);

void main ()
{
    double Array1 [10] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9, 10.0};
    double Array2 [11] = {-1.1, -2.2, -3.3, -4.4, -5.5, -6.6, -7.7, -8.8, -9.9, -10.0, -11.0};

    cout << "Average of Array1 is " << Average (10, Array1) << endl;
    cout << "Average of Array2 is " << Average (11, Array2) << endl;
}
```

My code:

```
 .386

 .model flat

  public    _Average

 .data

 .code

 _Average proc

    finit

    mov ecx, [esp + 4]      ; get the number of elements
    mov ebx, [esp + 8]      ; get the address of the array

    fld     REAL8 PTR [ebx]
    fadd    REAL8 PTR [ebx + 8]
    fadd    REAL8 PTR [ebx + 16]
    fadd    REAL8 PTR [ebx + 24]
    fadd    REAL8 PTR [ebx + 32]
    fadd    REAL8 PTR [ebx + 40]
    fadd    REAL8 PTR [ebx + 48]
    fadd    REAL8 PTR [ebx + 56]
    fadd    REAL8 PTR [ebx + 64]
    fadd    REAL8 PTR [ebx + 72]

    fdiv    REAL8 PTR [ebx + 72]
    ret
    _Average endp

    end
```

Comment: You should be using ECX as a loop counter and execute fadd inside the loop. You also need to divide by the number of elements and make sure it is not zero.

Comment: why not implement Average in C++ first, get the assembly output using the `-S` switch of g++, and then modify it as you wish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
_Average proc
  finit
  mov ecx, [esp + 4]      ; get the number of elements
  mov ebx, [esp + 8]      ; get the address of the array
  fldz
  jecxz   noelems
nextelem:
  fadd    REAL8 PTR [ebx]
  add     ebx, 8
  loop    nextelem
  fidiv   [esp + 4]
noelems:
  ret
_Average endp
```